# problems with Beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am having some trouble with my code, I looking to extract some links from a website and I am using BeautifulSoup 4.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
url ="http://www.mysite" 
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):  
    print(link.get('href'))
```

I get this message

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you give the URL that you are trying to access?

Comment: http://www.ouedkniss.com/fr/annonces/categorie.php?c=informatique

Comment: Code that you posted is working. I'm getting all links from that page. Post the actual code which gave you that error. Or state which version of BeautifulSoup and Python you are using

Comment: i think that the problem was with the version of BS, i made mistake by installing the version 3 and 4 (i missed with that). i deleted the file and tried to re-install it but when i run my code i get :   from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Comment: Try 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'